# iPhone get UTC Zulu time

Tags: iphone, time, nsdate

Will this

```
double systemTime = (double)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Return the time in UTC regardless of phone location and timezone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does. `NSDate` represents a timezone-independent universal time. In order to map it to a time zone, or to a non-European calendar, use `NSCalendar` and `NSTimeZone`. Read the Apple documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html).